# .NET Excel Add-in will load but wont start but only on some pcs

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2012, vsto

Have an excel add-in we built with C# and it installs and launches fine on most pc's but not on others.  The Addin launches a form that makes a connection to a SQL database, grabs some data and populates a worksheet.  On every PC, it installs fine and is listed in the Add-ins list and enabled, but on some pcs it will simply not launch/start while on others it will.  This is also true whether or not the user is an admin or not.

In one case, a non-admin user logged in to a pc and the pluging launched, but on another pc, a different user who has domain admin rights could not launch the add-in.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your Add-In contain any references to external libraries?  These libraries may not be installed on every PC.  Web Objects is a common one that can cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Was having a similar problem and resolved by removing entry located under Resiliency key in registry

```
HKCU -- > SOFTWARE -- > MICROSOFT --> OFFICE14 --> EXCEL -- > Resiliency --> DISABLED ITEMS
```